# What was the opinion of Swami Dayanand Saraswati about the Purva Mimamsa?

Tags: philosophy, purva-mimamsa, shad-darshana, dayananda-saraswati

What was the opinion of Swami Dayanand Saraswati, founder of Arya Samaj, about the Purva Mimamsa?

Comment: Can you clarify bit more? Swami Dayananda Saraswati accepted Purva Mimansa Sutras. What are you looking for?